# Crop tool doesn't fill background when increasing canvas size

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When increasing canvas size with crop tool in older versions of Photoshop, background filling occurred automatically, but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

I've tried to switch to the classic mode, but it does not help.

Is it possible to do as before?

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE!  I've taken the liberty to simplify your question a bit and remove courtesy phrases. We like questions to be as precise as possible without noise. If you disagree with my edits, you can roll back to your previous version or do some edits yourself.

Answer (score 4):

To automatically fill the background when increasing canvas size with the crop tool, the image has to have a *Background* layer. If it doesn't, the added pixels will be transparent.

[image]

You can turn your lowest layer into a *Background* layer, by selecting it and choosing *Layer > New > Background from Layer*.